# How to stub/mock a helper method for functional test in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocking

I'm wondering how to stub/mock a helper method in functional tests?
Thanks!

*(And Yes, I already googled & used the search - but couldn't find any working solution, strange!?)*

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427836/how-do-i-add-a-mocha-expectation-that-a-helper-method-will-be-called

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) documentation, specifically the `returns` method? You can tell Mocha what the mocked version of your method should send back, letting you set up both good and bad results, depending on what you're trying to test.

Comment: well the problem is not the return value, it's more the case how to 'find' the method to stub

@controller.stubs(:my_helper_method).returns('stubed value') doesn't work...