# How to add an expectation on a helper method in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

I have a controller which renders a view, lets say show.html.haml.

show.html.haml has a certain logic to call a helper method:

```
-if LOGIC
  = helper_method()
```

How do I test whether this helper_method is being called in my controller spec? I tried adding an expectation on ActionView::Base as explained here [How do I add a mocha expectation that a helper method will be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427836/how-do-i-add-a-mocha-expectation-that-a-helper-method-will-be-called)
but it does not work.

Comment: I think it might be better to test that the _output_ of the helper method is present rather than the fact that the helper method itself is called. Testing for method calls is brittle. I also wonder if this kind of testing should be in a controller spec or if it should be extracted into a more appropriate area (model perhaps?) where it can be tested more directly.

Comment: Agree with @carlosramireziii - this should be tested in an integration test. I recommend using [RSpec and Capybara](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara).